# ajax request returns an unexpected output with the correct output

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is the output I get from ajax request to php pdo:

`[{"sys_id":"1","task":"qwe","task_date":"11\/30\/2017 8:49 PM","task_person":"qwe","task_status":"0"},{"sys_id":"2","task":"asd","task_date":"11\/30\/2017 9:54 PM","task_person":"asd","task_status":"0"}]null`

As shown there is an excess `null` value which I cant figure out where it is coming from my code is:

```js
function selecttask(action) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../include/demo.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      action: action
    },
    success: function(data) {

    }
  }).done(function(data) {



  });
}
selecttask("selectall");
```

My demo.php is:

```
<?php
include_once("crud.php");
//include_once("../config/config.php");
//$con = new connect_pdo();
$crud = new Crud();

$action =  $_POST['action'];
$data =  $_POST['data'];
switch (strtolower($action)):
    case("selectall"):
        $table = "list_tbl";
        $selectall = $crud->selectall($table);

        echo json_encode($selectall, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        break;
    case("add"):
        $table = "list_tbl";
        $insert = $crud->insert($table,$data);

        echo json_encode($insert, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        break;


endswitch;
?>
```

Then crud is:

```
<?php
include_once("../config/config.php");

class Crud extends connect_pdo {

    public $_con;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_con = $this->dbh();
    }
    public function selectall($table_name) {

        $queryselectall = "Select * from {$table_name}";
        $selectall = $this->_con->prepare($queryselectall);
        if ($selectall->execute()) {
            if ($selectall->rowCount() > 0) {
                $result = $selectall->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            }else{
                echo array('error'=> TRUE, 'message'=> 'No result found.');
            }
        }
    }

    public function insert($table_name, $res) {

        parse_str($res, $data);

        $limit = count($data);
        $ctr = 0;
        $columns = "";
        $values = "";
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $ctr++;
            $columns.= "{$key}";
            $values .= ":{$key}";
            if ($ctr < $limit) {
                $columns.= ",";
                $values .= ",";
            }
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO {$table_name} ({$columns})VALUES({$values})";
        try {
            $create = $this->_con->prepare($query);
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $keys = ":{$key}";
                $create->bindValue($keys, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
            if ($create->execute()) {
                $lastinserted_id = $this->_con->lastInsertId();
                echo array('error' => FALSE, 'message' => 'Data added successfully.', 'lastinserted_id' => $lastinserted_id, 'query' => $query);
            } else {
                echo array('error' => TRUE, 'message' => 'Execution failed, please contact system support!');
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo array('error' => TRUE, 'message' => $ex);
        }
    }

}
?>
```

> From the above code I cant determine where the null is coming from.
>   Did I miss something that is why null is coming as result of ajax request

Comment: You're json_encoding twice...that can't help anything. The $crud->selectall() method should return an array containing the query results...it shouldn't echo anything.

Comment: And right now it returns nothing

Comment: @jcorry that was so dumb of me can you give it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a better architecture for your `Crud` class to handle DB interactions by running the queries and returning the results as an array (or throwing an exception if anything exceptional happens). Then your demo.php script can just get the array from the Crud class method and handle the output (json encoding, response output).